# iterate through a dictionary in django template

Tags: python, html, django-templates

```
{'provide a full refund of any money paid ': ['the ', 'dith ', 'with ', 'ande ', 'cor '], 'copyright laws of the place where you ar': ['e ', 'init ', ' or ', 'ate ', 's '], 'person or entity that provided you with ': ['the ', 'of ', 'ande ', ' or ', 'project '], 'michael s. hart is the originator of the': [' the ', '\n ', 's ', 'r ', ', ']}
```

How do i parse this django variable passed through my view to the html file.
I want to make this data to be displayed in the html file in form of a table where each keys values are shown

```
return render(request, 'notebook/instant_search.html', output)
```

i tried this in my html file where out put is the variable i am passing through my view

```
{% for key, value in output %}
   {{ key }} <br>
    {% for key2 in value %}
       {{ key2 }} <br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

also this:

```
{% for k in context %}
    {{  k }}
{% endfor %}
```

But i am not getting any output. Its blank nothing on the screen to display

Comment: Please provide us with code samples of what you tried until now. That way we can help you more effectively.

Comment: Done. Check now

Answer (score 7):

To start with, your `render` function isn't accepting the correct arguments and that is why nothing is appearing on your html template. You typed this:

```
return render(request, 'notebook/instant_search.html', output)
```

The correct one:

```
return render(request, 'notebook/instant_search.html', 'output':output)
```

The above will solve the problem of template not displaying data from the render function.

Next is the code that will iterate through the dictionary:

The following will display each item in the list

```
{% for k, v in output.items %}
    {% for i in v %}
        {{ i }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

while the code below will display each list

```
{% for k, v in output.items %}
    {{ v }}
{% endfor %}
```

References:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

Answer (score 2):

```
return render(request, 'notebook/instant_search.html', {"output":output})
```

Change this statement in the views file and then you will get the output by having

```
<table>
{% for key, value in output.items %}
<tr>
<td>{{key}}</td>
<td>{{value}}<td> <!-- you can also run for on values list -->
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate dictionary directly in the template:

```
<table>
{% for key, value in my_dict.items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td>{{value}}<td> <!-- you can also run for on values list -->
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

hope it helps

Comment: okay, I am sorry, did not had updated question while writing answer. if you run loop on output it won't work, since output is context object. you should add output to the context itself to run loop on output (in the views.py)
return render(request, 'notebook/instant_search.html', {"output":output})